# How to enter Naga Aspirant class as Samsaran?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, archetype

I'm interested in the Samsaran race for Mystic Past Life and want to enter Naga Aspirant for the Aspirant’s Bond. The problem is obviously that you need to be a nagaji for that class.

I can't take Racial Heritage because I don't start as human and I can't find any way to count as that to take the feat.  Is there another way?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already.

Comment: What spells are you looking for in the Aspirant Bond list?

Answer (score 1):

**Reincarnate**

There is some debate and GM discretion as to how Reincarnate fully works, but a lot of people argue that the only thing you lose from your previous race is anything related to your physical body (physical stats, natural weapons, a tail if you had one, etc). So have your Samsaran die and get reincarnated as a Nagaji. This is where the GM fiat, or a VERY lucky roll on your part, comes in. If you go by the chart in the spell description you have to roll a 100 and buy the GM dinner to get Nagaji as an option. But, if you manage to do it then the only things you lose from Samsaran are its Low Light Vision and its -2 Constitution.

Comment: This is the only solution I could come up with as well. But I dont think its a *good* solution.

Comment: Well, there is also "beg your DM to forgo the racial requirements for archetypes" or "say you were raised by Nagaji from childhood and effectively count as Nagaji for class requirements". All roads end with the DM handwaving something though.